# Image gallery block with CSS with different image dimension?

Tags: css, image-gallery

I was trying to achieve the below layout with CSS. Here is the layout snap:

https://archive.org/details/Untitled1_20161122

Without masonry as this is not possible with masonry I guess (row/column width/height both changes which is not the case in masonry, I might be wrong though). Is there a nice pure CSS solution. It would be much appreciated. I have been searching for a CSS solution for quite long. [www.bata.com](http://www.bata.com) for example have similar result in their homepage if that helps to explain the purpose, and without masonry as far as I am concerned.

Here is my code:

```css
.gallery {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: crimson;
    position: relative;
   }
   .col-20 {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
   }
   .col-40 {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
   }
   .col-60 {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
   }
   div {
    overflow: hidden;
   }
   img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
   }
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
         <div class="col-40">
          <img src="1.png" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-20">
          <img src="2.jpg" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-20">
          <img src="3.jpg" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-20">
          <img src="4.png" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-20">
          <img src="2.jpg" alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-20">
          <img src="3.jpg" alt="">
         </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please post a link to the website?

Comment: Also, I edited the question with a code snippet, so it would be awesome if you could upload the images somewhere and link them here...try https://archive.org/

Comment: Hi, I made the suggested edits. Thanks. Do you have any suggestion about the solution btw?

Comment: Can you upload the images to a service like http://archive.org so that we can see what you have so far? Also, by images I meant the images that you used in the `<img>` tags...Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Why don't you use a table for this effect? That way you can control `rowspan` and `colspan` **like a boss.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with a static layout, you could use a table with a fixed layout and no borders.

https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/

Set your images as backgrounds for the table with `background-size: cover;`

Then using width, colspan and rowspan,  create a fixed layout on your table.

[image]